# A light/ light/the light

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Everyone! Why is this correct:

> There was someone in the house because there was a light on inside.

As I know, light is uncountable. So correct to say the light/ light but not a light, isn't it?
Thanks!

Comment: Now I see ) But now I am confused with another meaning:  We would like to shine a light on this question. In this case a light isn't  a lamp but still they use " a".  I would write "to shine light".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `a light` means literally one single lamp, so the use of `a` is quite normal.

You seem to be assuming that the author is referring to the output of a lamp, which is indeed 'uncountable' but that is not what was intended.